# Cannot resolve method tailMap for TreeMap

Tags: java, dictionary, interface, treemap

Why does `TreeMap` of type `Map` not define the methods `tailMap` or `headMap`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.tailMap();  //cannot resolve method tailMap
```

With explicit cast it works:

```
((TreeMap<String, String>) map).tailMap("a");
```

With `NavigableMap` everything is fine:

```
NavigableMap<String, String> map1 = new TreeMap<>();
map1.tailMap("a");
```

If I'm right that's because of the interface `Map` lacking corresponding methods, in spite of the face that the object `map` is concrete implementation of class `TreeMap` that certainly does possess the such methods.

Just looking for more detailed explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The object of type `TreeMap` does have the method `tailMap`, but you are referencing it via a reference of type `Map`, which does not expose the `tailMap` method itself. That is why the compiler complains.

Note that Java is **statically typed**. This means that the compiler needs to make sure *at compile time* that there is a method to call regardless of the actual implementation.

Since you could have a `Map` implementation that **does not define** the `tailMap` method, the compiler won't allow you to invoke the `tailMap` method on an object referenced via `Map`.

Since the `NavigableMap` interface defines the method `tailMap`, you are able to invoke the method on any object referenced via `NavigableMap`. This also applies if you use `TreeMap` as reference type, since `TreeMap` implements `NavigableMap`. This is why the compiler does not complain in your second and third examples (the explicit cast and the `NavigableMap` reference declaration).

Comment: Indeed, `SortedMap` is the "highest" interface that defines the method. So as a rule of thumb, it is the one that should be used (just as a hint - the question was specifically about `NavigableMap`, so referring to that is fine here)

Comment: That is correct, `SortedMap` would be the best choice.